# Plotting networkx graph: node labels adjacent to nodes?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx

I am trying to plot association rules and am having a difficult time getting the node labels below to "follow" the nodes. That is, I would like each label to automatically be near its respective node without having to hard-code any values. The output from below doesn't even include some of the node labels. How can I make these labels dynamically follow the nodes?

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matlotlib.pyplot as plt    

df = pd.DataFrame({'node1': ['candy', 'cookie', 'beach', 'mark', 'black'],
                   'node2': ['beach', 'beach', 'cookie', 'beach', 'mark'], 
                   'weight': [10, 5, 3, 4, 20]})

G = nx.Graph()

for idx in df.index:
    node1 = df.loc[idx, 'node1']
    node2 = df.loc[idx, 'node2']
    weight = df.loc[idx, 'weight']
    G.add_edge(node1, node2, weight = weight)

nx.draw(G, node_size = 100)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos, font_size = 14, with_labels = True)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The `networkx` command `draw_networkx` takes care of that and does what your two different draw commands do. `nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, node_size=100, font_size = 14, with_labels = True)`
However, the labels are displayed exactly on top of the nodes. You'd have to look into how to add an offset to them.

Comment: I already know how to add the labels onto the nodes directly. I'm asking how to add the offset.

Comment: The command I posted at least takes care of the "dynamically following" of the nodes you requested. The labels are displayed on top of each node instead of placing them far away from them like in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
nx.draw(G, node_size = 100)
```

and then

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

you are creating two sets of positions. The solution is to first get the positions, and then use them for both, nodes and labels.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos = pos, node_size = 100)
# do stuff to pos if you want offsets
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos, font_size = 14, with_labels = True)
```